# У нее челка явно некрашена. - Явно некрашена - прилагательное?

Tags: прилагательные

По Розенталю:

1. При использовании в качестве пояснительных слов наречий меры и степени (весьма, крайне, очень, почти, совсем, вовсе и др.) частица не с причастием пишется слитно: совершенно невычитанная рукопись; совсем непроверенные цифры.

С другой стороны:

2. Пишется раздельно частица не с краткими формами причастия: рукопись не отредактирована; цитаты не проверены; работа не выполнена.

Вопросы:

I. Если причастие, с одной стороны, краткое, а с другой - при нем есть в качестве пояснительных слов наречия меры и степени, то писать это слово раздельно с НЕ, согласно первому правилу, или слитно, согласно второму?

II. При наличии таких пояснительных слов не переходит ли причастие в прилагательное?

Например:

На льду не заметны следы.

На льду почти (не)заметны следы.

У Лопатина:

•   Примечание. Как видно из примеров, причастие опознается по наличию зависимых слов. Бывают, однако, редкие случаи, когда зависимое слово не является признаком причастия. Напр., следует писать: у него усики явно крашеные (ср. явно искусственные, где слово явно употреблено при прилагательном); стены, раньше белёные, теперь покрыты зелёной краской (ср. стены, раньше белые).

Тогда, если при слове "крашен" есть наречие "явно", то "крашен" с НЕ пишется слитно, так как будет прилагательным, а по правилу прилагательные пишутся с НЕ слитно, независимо от наличия пояснительных слов:

У нее челка явно некрашена.

явно некрашена - краткое прилагательное

не крашена - краткое причастие.

Answer (score 2):

Прежде всего, "явно" не является наречием меры и степени. Наречия меры и степени отвечают на вопросы "сколько?" ("чуть-чуть"), "в какой мере?" ("еле-еле"), "в какой степени?" ("слегка") и показывают, насколько выполнено действие: "слекга покрашена", "полностью покрашена" и т. д. "Явно" - наречие, выражающее убежденность автора в факте совершения (не совершения) действия, а не меру этого действия.

Из сказанного очевидно, что краткое причастие "крашен" пишется с "не" в вашем случае раздельно.

Второе. Причастие не переходит в прилагательное при добавлении "не-", такого процесса не существует. Оно так и остается причастием с частицей "не-". По полной форме различие видно: в одном случае в суффиксе одинарное, во втором двойное "н".

В вашем случае можно употребить и наречие "не крашена", и прилагательное "некрашена". По смыслу они практически совпадают. В других случаях смысловые различия могут быть более выражены:

> Документ был явно недописан = документ не закончен
>
> Документ был явно не дописан = в документе нет дописок, приписок